# Left join without duplicating same columns

Tags: r

I have two data.frames similar to the following frames:

```
tmp1<-data.frame(col1=1:26,col2=LETTERS)
tmp2<-data.frame(col1=26:51,col3=LETTERS)
```

I want to merge the two data.frames by `col2` and `col3` without duplicating `col1` and without changing `tmp1`.

```
left_join(tmp1,tmp2,by=c("col2"="col3"))
```

Above code works, but it duplicates `col1`.

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
> merge(tmp1,tmp2[,-1,drop=F],by.x="col2",by.y="col3")
   col2 col1
1     A    1
2     B    2
3     C    3
4     D    4
5     E    5
6     F    6
7     G    7
8     H    8
9     I    9
10    J   10
11    K   11
12    L   12
13    M   13
14    N   14
15    O   15
16    P   16
17    Q   17
18    R   18
19    S   19
20    T   20
21    U   21
22    V   22
23    W   23
24    X   24
25    Y   25
26    Z   26
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(tmp1,tmp2 %>% select(col3),by=c("col2"="col3"))

#   col1 col2
#1     1    A
#2     2    B
#3     3    C
#4     4    D
#5     5    E
#6     6    F
#7     7    G
#8     8    H
#...
```